# Help identifying a fastener and finding a replacement

Tags: fastener

I've had a bed frame stored in a closet for years and have lost the fasteners with which to assemble it. It's an Ikea Heimdal frame; this item is discontinued and they no longer carry the fasteners needed to put the frame together.

The fasteners can be seen in the [assembly instructions here](http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/customer_service/assembly/H/H00095611.pdf), parts #100585 and #100013.
[image: Screenshot of assembly instructions]

One part is basically just a shank, the other an elongated head. They are unlike anything I've seen at the hardware store, so I would like to know what these pieces are called and where I can find replacements. I hope they are not unique to Ikea.

Comment: probably unique to IKEA .... you could use a long bolt with a tight fitting metal tube

Comment: @jsotola not unique - perhaps sizing wise they are  and would have been easier to order from the factory but not unique.

Comment: @Leo Whenever I have something like this I use a zip lock baggy for all hardware and even the tool and tape it around something - like those rails. The instructions I would hang either behind a head board or under the bed mattress again in a zip lock bag. They work great for keeping these things for future use.

Comment: the first thing you need to do here is determine the thread size as it needs to screw into the end of the bed rail. You also need to measure the drilled hole to determine the maximum  diameter of the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

For 100013, use "threaded rod", commonly known as "all thread" and cut with a grinder or Dremel tool to size. Any hardware store will have it, but you'll probably need metric.

For 100585, I'd try "female threaded round standoffs", you can get them partially threaded so you can tighten them down. (Looking at the instructions, I don't think threadlocker is going to work) Otherwise, they make closed end standoffs with a hex head at the end.

Answer (score 1):

1. 100585 Cylindrical Hex Head Nut.
2. 100013 Threaded Rod - aka All thread,it is nothing but thread hence the name.

Try here:
MISUMI (this is probably easier for you to understand what you need to order).
https://us.misumi-ec.com/vona2/detail/110300250450/

Or From :
https://www.belmetric.com/allen-socket-nuts-c-3_1506/nskt8x16ss-allen-socket-nut-stainless-p-9462.html